# Java Firefox webdriver unable to navigate with previous execution cookies .,, basically with cookies already stored in profile

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Java Firefox webdriver unable to navigate with previous execution cookies .,, basically unable to access with  already stored in profile cookies

Tried with cookie class driver.manage().addcookies, not refreshing even after refreshing in different ways

Tried setting default profile..
 Still not worked.

Could anyone please advise what changes to do to access Firefox with existing profile and cookies

Comment: please provide the logic used i.e. script

Comment: Please post more of your code that you tried